# Add a dynamic header parameter value to <script> tags for loading js files

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to add a dynamic header param value (like session={someValue} for loading js scripts in a index.html file?

My goal is to prevent people from loading js sources if they do not have a valid session id. The user gets the session id from a separate login.html and he will then be forwarded to another url path which contains the session id as a path parameter. Then in the index.html file I can read the session id from the path param. However, this index.html will then load many js sources by using the tag `<script src="lib/somefile.js" /script>` . But this loading process should include the dynamic session id somehow... Any suggestions, ideas?

Comment: It doesn't really sound like something that would be as simple as adding something to a script tag, and outputting the session in the markup doesn't really sound like a great idea either.

Comment: did you want something like this? <script src="lib/somefile.js?sessionId=10234" </script>

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to set a cookie on the login page and check for that in your static file server.

Comment: How would you prevent someone from loading the js lib directly by calling the path to the js file with a cookie?

Comment: I would require the cookie to be present and valid. Generally this is not really a good idea for static files though. I recommend not even bothering with this

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on the server-side. For example, on your index, after succesfull login, include your js files.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
// <script type="javascript" src="source.js?myParameter=1" />
// read value of myParameter from within the script as it runs
// can this just work by using a global variable?

var filepath;

(function () {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    var currentScript = scripts[i];
    if (currentScript.src.indexOf("myParameter") === -1) {
      continue;
    }
    console.log(currentScript.src);

    if (currentScript && currentScript.src) {
      var scriptSrcArray = currentScript.src.split("=");
      console.log(scriptSrcArray);
      widgetType = scriptSrcArray[1];
    }
  }

}());
```